# How to set max length on integerfield Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Okay so I need to have my field have a maximum of 10 integers allowed to be entered. I tried `MaxValueValidator` but I figured out that this just needs a value thats lower than the set value. I want to be able to enter a maximum of 10 numbers, so it should work if I enter just one number, but also if I enter 10.

Code ex:

```
class Random(models.Model):
     code=models.IntegerField
```

Comment: max_length as a function doesnt work on IntFields apparently, thats why i need an alternative to this. Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with `validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try something like below? (code not tested.)

```
#add this import statement at top

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

#A function to check length
def validate_length(value):
    an_integer = value
    a_string = str(an_integer)
    length = len(a_string)
    if length > 10:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is above 10 digits')
        )

#Add to model field
class MyModel(models.Model):
    validate_len = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_length])
```

refer below
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/

Comment: "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'" this is the error that was recieved when running it. Edit: removed the params line and it worked, it just gives the error. Awesome, thanks man^^

Comment: Yep. To keep it simple I will remove that params

Answer (score 0):

The `RegexValidator` could be used with the correct regex. If changing `IntegerField` to `CharField` isn't a big deal, you could also write a validator to ensure `code` has a 10 digit maximum. It could be a custom validator that verifies each character is a digit and there are less than 10 total along with any other requirements you may have.

Comment: Well thats how it was requested to be. Could you give me an example on how you would go about that validator on the models.CharField? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ````code=models.IntegerField(validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])````. I thought RegexValidator couldn't be used with IntegerField but I think I may be incorrect.  Try that solution for either ````IntegerField```` or ````CharField```` and see if it works.

Comment: Tried it with IntegerField, didn't raise any errors but it didn't do anything for some reason, still able to enter more than 10 numbers. Tried it with CharField, that's gonna need the max_length attribute and some other errors.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe the regex syntax is different in ````RegexValidator````? Django documentation says ````RegexValidator```` searches for the value using ````re.search()````. When I use the regex I wrote above directly with ````re.search()````, I'm getting the correct results. Make sure the regex is correct as I had a typo in my initial comment.