# Response 400 Bad Request while posting a list

Tags: python, json, api, post, python-requests

I am trying to POST a list to the DRF server and I'm getting 400 bad request response (The URL and token are correct, the server is live)

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

x = [2423, 2342, 443]
y = [532, 5432, 543]
w = [7456, 256, 564]
h = [2345, 6543, 874]

Boxes = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    Boxes.append({'X': x[i], 'Y': y[i], 'W': w[i], 'H': h[i]})

res = json.dumps(Boxes)


r = requests.post(
    "http://art1x.pythonanywhere.com/snippets/",
    data=json.dumps({"X": res,
                     "Y": '0',
                     "W": '0',
                     "H": '0',
                     "Amount": '0'
                     }),
    headers={'Authorization': 'Token 353101b2657b3779199777984c131f33b78656be',
             "Content-Type": "application/json"},
)
print(r.status_code)
```

I am converting `Boxes` to a JSON object and then posting it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this: `print(r.json())` and you will see the error message

> {'X': ['Ensure this field has no more than 100 characters.']}

Indeed `len(res)` has 132 characters. You may need to shorten it

To extend the allowed length limit ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433483)) you could try:

```
#Add to model field
class MyModel(models.Model):
    validate_len = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Comment: Is there any way to extend the allowed length on the server side? Is it done via models.CharField(max_length)??

Comment: yes, I guess it could be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433483)